# Spring Boot Actuator sensitive role

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have enable all actuators to be sensitive.

```
management.context-path=/manage
management.security.enabled=true
management.security.role=NOACCESS
endpoints.sensitive=true
```

I see for example metrics endpoint show correctly

```
  "metricsEndpoint": {
    "prefix": "endpoints.metrics",
    "properties": {
      "id": "metrics",
      "sensitive": true,
      "enabled": true
    }
```

However if I access this with a user without that ROLE it still works.

Comment: Hard to tell. Any custom security configuration in your app? What Spring Boot version are you using?

Comment: Have you included the spring security dependency in your project?

Comment: Spring boot 1.3.1. Yes. I actually added added a preauthentication filter and spring security ldap too but the role checks are not working but see security events firing.